# Why is the time complexity for Bubble Sort O(n^2) as opposed to O(n^3)?

Tags: python, sorting, time-complexity, bubble-sort

I'm new to Python and Big O notation and was thinking about what time complexity the Bubble sort algorithm should have while writing it as an exercise. Here's the code I wrote:

```
def bubblesort(num_list, sort_type):
    """Returns the list of numbers in ascending order, descending order"""
    ite = len(num_list) - 1

    if sort_type == "asc":
        for i in range(ite):
            for n in range(ite - i):
                if num_list[n] > num_list[n + 1]:
                    temp = num_list[n + 1]
                    num_list[n + 1] = num_list[n]
                    num_list[n] = temp
    elif sort_type == "desc":
        for i in range(ite):
            for n in range(ite - i):
                if num_list[n] < num_list[n + 1]:
                    temp = num_list[n + 1]
                    num_list[n + 1] = num_list[n]
                    num_list[n] = temp
    else:
        pass
    return num_list
```

Since the outer loop, inner loop and conditional all grow linearly as the input size is increased, I figured that the time complexity should be O(n*n*n) = O(n^3) but Google says that it's O(n^2), and I don't understand why it isn't cubic.

Comment: Why do you think, the condition would take longer time for bigger `n`s?

Comment: OT but consider using multi-assignments like `num_list[n], num_list[n+1] = num_list[n+1], num_list[n]` instead of three assignments like in your code.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought the condition was a loop. :)